# React Native Webview not resetting injected JavaScript

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview

I have to retrieve the html content of the WebView when a certain URL is reached. To do this I inject `window.postMessage(document.documentElement.innerHTML);` using the injectJavaScript function provided by the WebView component when this URL is reached.

This works fine the first time, but when trying the same thing again after a restart, redirects are not handled and the injectedJavaScript is called at the first page as if it was never removed. This behaviour is present on iOS, not on Android.

Anyone encountered the same problem or has a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `react-native-webview` package:

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

<WebView
    ref={(ref) => { this.webview = ref; }}
    source={{ uri: this.state.webViewUrl }}
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
    injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
    onMessage={this._onMessage} // only if you want connection back
/>
```

and you can pass `js` code:

```
const jsCode = `
document.querySelector('button.btn-success').addEventListener("click", function() {  
    window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify({type: "click", message : "ok"}));
}); 
true;
`
```